# How to pass table-row index to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, drop-down-menu, tablerow

I have some php code that is creating an html table. Within it I have a form where I have different dropdown menus that have onChange events. I need to pass into the javascript function the table-row index. Is there any way to do this? If so could you please provide an example. Thank you!

My php code is listed below:

```
<?php
echo"
  <table id='inputTable'>
    <form id='trade' name='trade' method='post' action=''>
    <tr id = 'labelRow0' name = 'labelRow0' style='display:table-row'>
      <td>Spread Type</td>
      <td>Option/Future</td>
      <td>Year</td>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Strike</td>
      <td>Call/Put</td>
      <td>Buy/Sell</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Delta</td>
      <td>House</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = 'inputRow0' name = 'inputRow0' style='display:table-row'>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges(0)' name='spreadType[]' id='spreadType0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Spread'>Spread
        <option value='Fly'>Fly
        <option value='Straddle'>Straddle
        <option value='Strangle'>Strangle
        <option value='Tree'>Tree
        <option value='Condor'>Condor
        <option value='Ladder'>Ladder
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='optionFuture[]' id='optionFuture0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Option'>Option
        <option value='Future'>Future
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='year[]' id='year0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Front'>Front
        <option value='Short'>Short
        <option value='Red'>Red
        <option value='Green'>Green
        <option value='Blue'>Blue
        <option value='Gold'>Gold
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='month[]' id='month0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='January'>January
        <option value='February'>February
        <option value='March'>March
        <option value='April'>April
        <option value='May'>May
        <option value='June'>June
        <option value='July'>July
        <option value='August'>August
        <option value='September'>September
        <option value='October'>October
        <option value='November'>November
        <option value='December'>December
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='strike[]' id='strike0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='100'>100
        <option value='99'>99
        <option value='98'>98
        <option value='97'>97
        <option value='96'>96
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges()' name='callPut[]' id='callPut0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Call'>Call
        <option value='Put'>Put
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='buySell[]' id='buySell0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Buy'>Buy
        <option value='Sell'>Sell
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='price[]' id='price0' size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='quantity[]' id='quantity0' size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='delta[]' id='delta0' size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges()' name='house[]' id='house0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='001 - First Options'>001 - First Options
        <option value='020 - Bache'>020 - Bache
        <option value='033 - FC Stone'>033 - FC Stone
        <option value='Other'>Other
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = 'otherRow0' name = 'otherRow' style='display:none'>
      <td><input type='text' name='spreadFormation[]' id='spreadFormation0' size='9'/></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='otherHouse[]' id='otherHouse0' size='22'/></td>
    </tr>";

$baseLabel = 'labelRow';
$baseInput = 'inputRow';
$baseStr = 'otherRow';
$baseOptionFuture = 'optionFuture';
$baseYear = 'year';
$baseMonth = 'month';
$baseStrike = 'strike';
$baseCallPut = 'callPut';
$baseBuySell = 'buySell';
$baseSpreadType = 'spreadType';
$basePrice = 'price';
$baseQuantity = 'quantity';
$baseDelta = 'delta';
$baseHouse = 'house';
$baseSpreadFormation = 'spreadFormation';
$baseOtherHouse = 'otherHouse';

for ( $i = 1; $i < 20; $i++ ) 
{
  $labelId = $baseLabel.$i;
  $inputRow = $baseInput.$i;
  $otherId = $baseStr.$i;
  $optionFutureId = $baseOptionFuture.$i;
  $yearId = $baseYear.$i;
  $monthId = $baseMonth.$i;
  $strikeId = $baseStrike.$i;
  $callPutId = $baseCallPut.$i;
  $buySellId = $baseBuySell.$i;
  $spreadTypeId = $baseSpreadType.$i;
  $priceId = $basePrice.$i;
  $quantityId = $baseQuantity.$i;
  $deltaId = $baseDelta.$i;
  $houseId = $baseHouse.$i;
  $spreadFormationId = $baseSpreadFormation.$i;
  $otherHouseId = $baseOtherHouse.$i;

  echo"
    <tr id = $labelId name = $labelId style='display:none'>
      <td>Spread Type</td>
      <td>Option/Future</td>
      <td>Year</td>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Strike</td>
      <td>Call/Put</td>
      <td>Buy/Sell</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Delta</td>
      <td>House</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = $inputRow name = $inputRow style='display:none'>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges()' name='spreadType[]' id='spreadType0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Spread'>Spread
        <option value='Fly'>Fly
        <option value='Straddle'>Straddle
        <option value='Strangle'>Strangle
        <option value='Tree'>Tree
        <option value='Condor'>Condor
        <option value='Ladder'>Ladder
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='optionFuture[]' id=$optionFutureId>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Option'>Option
        <option value='Future'>Future
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='year[]' id=$yearId>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Front'>Front
        <option value='Short'>Short
        <option value='Red'>Red
        <option value='Green'>Green
        <option value='Blue'>Blue
        <option value='Gold'>Gold
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='month[]' id=$monthId>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='January'>January
        <option value='February'>February
        <option value='March'>March
        <option value='April'>April
        <option value='May'>May
        <option value='June'>June
        <option value='July'>July
        <option value='August'>August
        <option value='September'>September
        <option value='October'>October
        <option value='November'>November
        <option value='December'>December
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='strike[]' id=$strikeId>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='100'>100
        <option value='99'>99
        <option value='98'>98
        <option value='97'>97
        <option value='96'>96
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges()' name='callPut[]' id=$callPutId>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Call'>Call
        <option value='Put'>Put
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='buySell[]' id=$buySellId>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Buy'>Buy
        <option value='Sell'>Sell
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='price[]' id=$priceId size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='quantity[]' id=$quantityId size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='delta[]' id=$deltaId size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges()' name='house[]' id = $houseId>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='001 - First Options'>001 - First Options
        <option value='020 - Bache'>020 - Bache
        <option value='033 - FC Stone'>033 - FC Stone
        <option value='Other'>Other
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = $otherId name = $otherId style='display:none'>
      <td><input type='text' name='spreadFormation[]' id=$spreadFormationId size='9'/></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='otherHouse[]' id=$otherHouseId size='22'/></td>
    </tr>
  ";
}
echo "</table>
  <input id='submitButton' type='submit' name='submit' type='submit' value='submit' />
  </form>";
?>
```

Comment: I have put an id with the row number on the <td> element, so I can easily determine which row I was on.

Comment: How do I pass that into my function then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im use to Zend, so this is how I usually do it, isntead of echoing html, just type out the html, and then use `<?for:?>` syntax. Like the following.

```
 <table id='inputTable'>
    <form id='trade' name='trade' method='post' action=''>
    <tr id = 'labelRow0' name = 'labelRow0' style='display:table-row'>
      <td>Spread Type</td>
      <td>Option/Future</td>
      <td>Year</td>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Strike</td>
      <td>Call/Put</td>
      <td>Buy/Sell</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Delta</td>
      <td>House</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = 'inputRow0' name = 'inputRow0' style='display:table-row'>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges()' name='spreadType[]' id='spreadType0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Spread'>Spread
        <option value='Fly'>Fly
        <option value='Straddle'>Straddle
        <option value='Strangle'>Strangle
        <option value='Tree'>Tree
        <option value='Condor'>Condor
        <option value='Ladder'>Ladder
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='optionFuture[]' id='optionFuture0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Option'>Option
        <option value='Future'>Future
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='year[]' id='year0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Front'>Front
        <option value='Short'>Short
        <option value='Red'>Red
        <option value='Green'>Green
        <option value='Blue'>Blue
        <option value='Gold'>Gold
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='month[]' id='month0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='January'>January
        <option value='February'>February
        <option value='March'>March
        <option value='April'>April
        <option value='May'>May
        <option value='June'>June
        <option value='July'>July
        <option value='August'>August
        <option value='September'>September
        <option value='October'>October
        <option value='November'>November
        <option value='December'>December
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='strike[]' id='strike0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='100'>100
        <option value='99'>99
        <option value='98'>98
        <option value='97'>97
        <option value='96'>96
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges()' name='callPut[]' id='callPut0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Call'>Call
        <option value='Put'>Put
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='buySell[]' id='buySell0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Buy'>Buy
        <option value='Sell'>Sell
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='price[]' id='price0' size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='quantity[]' id='quantity0' size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='delta[]' id='delta0' size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges()' name='house[]' id='house0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='001 - First Options'>001 - First Options
        <option value='020 - Bache'>020 - Bache
        <option value='033 - FC Stone'>033 - FC Stone
        <option value='Other'>Other
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = 'otherRow0' name = 'otherRow' style='display:none'>
      <td><input type='text' name='spreadFormation[]' id='spreadFormation0' size='9'/></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='otherHouse[]' id='otherHouse0' size='22'/></td>
    </tr>";
<?php 
$baseLabel = 'labelRow';
$baseInput = 'inputRow';
$baseStr = 'otherRow';
$baseOptionFuture = 'optionFuture';
$baseYear = 'year';
$baseMonth = 'month';
$baseStrike = 'strike';
$baseCallPut = 'callPut';
$baseBuySell = 'buySell';
$baseSpreadType = 'spreadType';
$basePrice = 'price';
$baseQuantity = 'quantity';
$baseDelta = 'delta';
$baseHouse = 'house';
$baseSpreadFormation = 'spreadFormation';
$baseOtherHouse = 'otherHouse';
?>

<?php for ( $i = 1; $i < 20; $i++ ) :?>
<?php
  $labelId = $baseLabel.$i;
  $inputRow = $baseInput.$i;
  $otherId = $baseStr.$i;
  $optionFutureId = $baseOptionFuture.$i;
  $yearId = $baseYear.$i;
  $monthId = $baseMonth.$i;
  $strikeId = $baseStrike.$i;
  $callPutId = $baseCallPut.$i;
  $buySellId = $baseBuySell.$i;
  $spreadTypeId = $baseSpreadType.$i;
  $priceId = $basePrice.$i;
  $quantityId = $baseQuantity.$i;
  $deltaId = $baseDelta.$i;
  $houseId = $baseHouse.$i;
  $spreadFormationId = $baseSpreadFormation.$i;
  $otherHouseId = $baseOtherHouse.$i;
?>

    <tr id = <?= $labelId ?> name = <?= $labelId  ?>style='display:none'>
      <td>Spread Type</td>
      <td>Option/Future</td>
      <td>Year</td>
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Strike</td>
      <td>Call/Put</td>
      <td>Buy/Sell</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Delta</td>
      <td>House</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = <?= $inputRow ?> name = <?= $inputRow ?>style='display:none'>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges()' name='spreadType[]' id='spreadType0'>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Spread'>Spread
        <option value='Fly'>Fly
        <option value='Straddle'>Straddle
        <option value='Strangle'>Strangle
        <option value='Tree'>Tree
        <option value='Condor'>Condor
        <option value='Ladder'>Ladder
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='optionFuture[]' id=<?= $optionFutureId ?>>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Option'>Option
        <option value='Future'>Future
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='year[]' id=<?= $yearId ?>>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Front'>Front
        <option value='Short'>Short
        <option value='Red'>Red
        <option value='Green'>Green
        <option value='Blue'>Blue
        <option value='Gold'>Gold
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='month[]' id=<?= $monthId ?>>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='January'>January
        <option value='February'>February
        <option value='March'>March
        <option value='April'>April
        <option value='May'>May
        <option value='June'>June
        <option value='July'>July
        <option value='August'>August
        <option value='September'>September
        <option value='October'>October
        <option value='November'>November
        <option value='December'>December
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='strike[]' id=<?= $strikeId ?>>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='100'>100
        <option value='99'>99
        <option value='98'>98
        <option value='97'>97
        <option value='96'>96
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges(<?= $i ?>)' name='callPut[]' id= <?= $callPutId ?>>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Call'>Call
        <option value='Put'>Put
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name='buySell[]' id=<?= $buySellId ?>>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='Buy'>Buy
        <option value='Sell'>Sell
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='price[]' id=<?= $priceId ?> size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='quantity[]' id= <?= $quantityId ?> size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='delta[]' id= <?= $deltaId ?> size='9'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select onchange='testChanges(<?= $i ?>)' name='house[]' id = <?= $houseId ?>>
        <option value=''>
        <option value='001 - First Options'>001 - First Options
        <option value='020 - Bache'>020 - Bache
        <option value='033 - FC Stone'>033 - FC Stone
        <option value='Other'>Other
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = $otherId name = $otherId style='display:none'>
      <td><input type='text' name='spreadFormation[]' id= <?= $spreadFormationId ?> size='9'/></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='otherHouse[]' id= <?= $otherHouseId ?> size='22'/></td>
    </tr>


<? endfor; ?>



</table>
<input id='submitButton' type='submit' name='submit' type='submit' value='submit' />
 </form>
```

Comment: Ya I really just need a number and my names are in an array.

Comment: Ya I just tried it and it didn't work. The problem is that the $i isn't being treated as a php variable but rather a string.

Comment: Yeah i changed it, I find it clearer to not echo html, if you can use phtml instead. Edit: phtml is the same as php.

Comment: hmm, No i dont believe so. It should work regardless, Sorry I havnt done straight php in a while, If you just type html instead of echo does it appear or does it throw an error?

Using shorthand php clears things up with markup.

<?for :?>
   Insert html

<?endfor ;?>

Comment: I just tested it. It would work fine without zend, Il post another answer to show the different constructs.

Comment: It says that the value being passed is undefined. That is with zend. A weird thing also happened and that was that rows 1-19 weren't hidden.

Comment: Nevermind I'm an idiot it worked but I still get that error with it not hiding the rows.

Comment: Ok I also was able to fix that. Just needed to add a space in between the variable and the style property.

Comment: Well wait a second man. I only get a value for $i passed to the javascript function if the display property is not set to non for the labelRow. Any ideas?

Comment: Not fully understanding what you mean, is the html being generated properly ie is the row number showing up in the function call?  
Are you saying that the function isnt triggering?

Comment: Any chance I can get the javascript too? Then i can test it on my side.

Comment: Just remember to put in the <?= $i ?> in every function call. The row should be fine.

Comment: I figured it out man. My next question for you is that the best way for me to get this done is to do it implementing a singleton class for my javascript and being able to call the same instance of that singleton class for the different changes. Are you familiar with how to do something like that. If so I can send you my javascript code.

Comment: Yeah I am fairly familiar with that. I would call the same instance. This looks like the calculation is fairly reusable.

Comment: Yeah I tried implementing this earlier so I have some tries at it commented out and then I have the function that we just worked with. Can I email the .js file to you by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Continuation of other answer:
Clear up your code by using shorthands.

Then inject the loop number `<?= $i ?>` indication row number

```
Remember <?=  is the same as echo
```

Bunch of different shorthands

IF/ELSE

```
<? if(true): ?>

<? else: ?>

<? endif; ?>
```

WHILE

```
<?php while (expr):?>
    statement
    ...
<?php endwhile;?>
```

```
<?php for($i = 5; $i < 20; $i++):?>


   <b> Number : <?= $i ?> ?>


<?php endfor; ?>

</body>
```